# Display Video with Media Player and fill screen without distorting the Video

Tags: java, android, android-video-player

I think the title says everything you need to know...at the moment my Video doesn't fit the whole screen, but It's not distorted... Now...how to make it filling the screen without get distorted?

Comment: I am afraid that the title does not say it all as you hoped. It would be helpful to see your current code in order to understand what you have tried thus far. Results of your own conducted research would also be helping.

Comment: @Ben I have tried many things..Like fill the Video Player with whole screen.. But than the Video is distorted. I think i need some Code who Resize the Video to the screen.